# Navigation bar not appearing after delegation setup

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a `UILabel` in my `ViewController` that has a `NavigationController` (let's say view controller A) with a tap gesture recognizer attached to the label. When the label is tapped another view appears (let's call it B). The user picks some text in B and the view dismisses back to A with the label text updated with the selection. So I created a delegation between A and B to get the selection. The problem is that I do not see the `NavigationBar` when B appears. Is there a way to fix this?

ViewController A

```
@IBOutlet weak var sectionName: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sectionLabelTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelTapped(_:)))
    sectionName.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    sectionName.addGestureRecognizer(sectionLabelTap)
}

@objc func labelTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let sectionNameVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SectionName") as! SectionNameTableViewController
    sectionNameVC.selectionNameDelegate = self
    sectionNameVC.userData = userData
    present(sectionNameVC, animated: true, completion: nil)  
}
```

Comment: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: Bool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display the Navigation bar the `UIViewController` needs to have a `UINavigationController`.

You can add that `sectionNameVC` ViewController into a `UINavigationController` to persevere the present animation.

In that case your code might look something like this:

```
@objc func labelTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let sectionNameVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SectionName") as! SectionNameTableViewController
        sectionNameVC.selectionNameDelegate = self
        sectionNameVC.userData = userData
        let naviagtionController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sectionNameVC)
        present(naviagtionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Or you can simply call `pushViewController` on the View Controller A's navigation Controller, like this:

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sectionNameVC, animated: true)`

This will add `sectionNameVC` into the  View Controller A's navigation Controller stack. In this case the transition animation will be different, the `sectionNameVC` will come from your right.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the concept between *"Presenting"* View Controller & *"Navigating"* the View Controller. You will get the answer, once you understood the concept. Here, it is..

1. When you are presenting the ViewController, you are completely replacing the stack container to the new view controller.

**STACK holds the addresses of the ViewControllers you push or pop via navigating.**

e.g:

```
    present(sectionNameVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

1. On the other hand, if you are navigating to other view controller by pushing it. In this case, you can go back to previous controller by simple popping the ViewController address from stack.

e.g:

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sectionNameVC, animated: true)

   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

So, If you navigate then, only you will get navigation Bar.

Now, in your case, you are presenting the ViewController and hence, navigation bar is not showing.